# having both developing and released version of windows 8 app store

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am developing a windows 8 store app with C#. I have released it on the store and also I am continuing my development for the next versions. How can I have both developing version and store version install on my computer? I need to be able to test the store version while keep adding features and fixing bugs.

When I change the code and try to run, I get a message that it will overwrite the store version which is already installed on my computer. It seems to be related to the fact they have the same package name in the manifest but I am not sure if modifying it is the best way and if modification would cause a problem later when I want to release the next versions.

Comment: There is one thing you can *try*, though I'm not sure it will work. You may be able to change the package name in your developing version. You can also create a Windows 8 VM and have the store version installed in there. In general though, you are not supposed to be able to do what you are asking. You can swap between the two versions by installing one over the other, in case you need to go back and test the old version. This will wipe your data and settings, but you can copy those out of the Packages folder and then paste them back in after reinstall.

Comment: I should note that the idea here is that by the time it gets into the store it should be fully tested and ready to go. Any bugs that may be in it should be in your new version (or fixed in your new version), and can still be tested there.

Comment: Thanks @NateDiamond for your comments. The approach you suggested is what I thought in the beginning but seems too manual and I guess there should be a better way. Also having two version does not seems quite natural to me as two developing lines. Also I did not said that I want this because of bug fixing. It is always wise to have the latest store version to make sure we can see users' experience to follow up feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, I dont think there is an easy solution for you. You might be able to do it with some powershell but that would still make it quite a manual process. Looking forward however, I would seriously consider using Visual Studio Online (TFS Source control in the cloud) to managing your source code.
Here is two guides on how to get started:

[Getting started with Visual Studio Online](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/connect-to-vs.aspx)

[How to upload source](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/tfs/2Ea9290913-How-to-Upload-Code-to-TFS-Cloud-Repository-by-Visual-Studio.html)

What you should do every time you make a release of your app is tobranch your development source code into a release branch. - A branch is basically like a folder containing a snapshot of your code.
This means you can have a development branch where you are working on your next version, and then a branch for every released version of your app. Whenever you want to return to released versions of the app, then you can always open the branch containing the specific release and redeploy the app to your device. Here is a guide on branching as well:

[Guide on Branching and Merging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jjameson/archive/2010/12/03/branching-for-a-release-in-team-foundation-server.aspx)

Comment: Exactly branching was the first concept came to my mind but I wish there were a simpler way.